# Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'Day' error

Tags: swift, data-persistence

In my app i tried to make saving data with data persistence but i get this error:
Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'Day' error.

Here is my code:

```
class Day: NSObject, NSCoding { // NEMA NSCODING I NSOBJECT
var dayName: String
var subjects: [Subject]?

init(dayName: String) {
    self.dayName = dayName
}

struct PropertyKey {
    static var dayName = "dayName"
    static var subjects = "subjects"
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(dayName, forKey: PropertyKey.dayName)
    aCoder.encode(subjects, forKey: PropertyKey.subjects)
}

// Archiving paths
static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("workingDays")//-namesto meals

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    guard let dayName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.dayName) as? String else {
        os_log("Unable to decode the dayName for a Day object.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return nil
    }
    let subjects = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.subjects) as? [Subject]
    self.init(dayName: dayName)
}
```

}

And here is the other class:

```
class Subject: Day {
var subjectName: String
var startsAt: String?
init(dayName: String,subjectName: String) {
    self.subjectName = subjectName
    super.init(dayName: dayName)
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder) // here I get the error
}
```

}

Am I going to save the data this way with implementing data persistence  only in Day class and why do I get that error?
I am a beginner and I'm doing it based on this apple documentation -

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjWoIHk4uvXAhUHaFAKHbQFCHcQFghbMAs&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fcontent%2Freferencelibrary%2FGettingStarted%2FDevelopiOSAppsSwift%2FPersistData.html&usg=AOvVaw24H5Uo4RyRY7NYIlztlgCj

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by calling `self.init` in `init?(coder` of `Day`. That call makes the initializer `convenient` and the subclass is not able to fulfill the requirements to call a designated initializer.

The solution is to initialize the properties directly

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.dayName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.dayName) as! String
    self.subjects = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.subjects) as? [Subject]
}
```

By the way: You are encoding **always** `dayName` as a **non-optional** string so it never can be `nil` when being decoded. The `guard` is useless.

In the subclass you might need to add code to en-/decode the properties of the subclass and call `super` to consider also the properties of the superclass.

```
class Subject: Day {
    var subjectName: String
    var startsAt: String?

    init(dayName: String, subjectName: String) {
        self.subjectName = subjectName
        super.init(dayName: dayName)
    }

    override func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        super.encode(with: aCoder)
        aCoder.encode(subjectName, forKey: "subjectName")
        aCoder.encode(startsAt, forKey: "startsAt")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        subjectName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "subjectName") as! String
        startsAt = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "startsAt") as? String
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

The question for the sense of using a subclass as property in its superclass is another story

Comment: Actually now I'm not sure what will this code do. Will it save the data from these classes permanently or do I have to write some other code in order to make that.Thanks for the help I am pretty new around here.

Answer (score 2):

By definition of Required Initializers-:

> **Write the `required` modifier before the definition of a class initializer to indicate that every subclass of the class must
>   implement that initializer**:
>
> **You do not write the `override` modifier when overriding a required designated initializer:**

In your case you made `convenience initialiser` of superclass `required`, so subclass have to implement it now -:

Code Correction-:

```
class Subject: Day {
    var subjectName: String
    var startsAt: String?
    init(dayName: String,subjectName: String) {
        self.subjectName = subjectName
        super.init(dayName: dayName)
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


}
```

Comment: I tried doing that and i get that fatal error "init(coder:) has not been implemented"...